# Node.js as service, exec doesn't work

Tags: node.js, batch-file, exec, child-process

I'm running Node.js project as service using nssm. When user clicks button on my nodejs website it should run 
`require('child_process').exec('cmd /c batfile.bat', function({ res.send(somedata); });`
but instead it just skips running bat file and jumps to `res.send(somedata)`. Why is that?
When I run Node.js using cmd and `npm start server.js` it works fine. How can I make exec work while running nodejs as service?

Edit, some code:

```
require('child_process').exec('cmd /c batfile.bat', function(){

        var log = fs.readFileSync('logs/batlog.log', 'utf8');
        var html = fs.readFileSync('logs/batlog.htm', 'utf8');
        var json = {"log": log, "html": html};
        res.send(json);   

      });
```

and the batfile.bat is supposed to generate those 2 files but it just doesn't if I run nodejs as service.

Comment: Can we see some code?  Maybe a problem with how you are controlling the child process.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with execFile. The executable file would not run when the nodejs script is running as a service using nssm.  But if I run the script in command prompt, it works fine. Have you found a solution?